# Concatenating variable values in Python script for export DDP as mxd via saveACopy method?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

i am building a script, most of which i found on here, that exports my data driven pages as mxds.  I need it to save the mxd by a specific attribute in the shapefile and am running into an error when trying with two attributes.  It works with 1 attribute but i can't combine them.

```
import arcpy  
a = 'L_NAME'

b = 'PAR_NUM'

c = a + b



mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\jcarl\Desktop\Presentation\P_Litwin.mxd")  
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages  
for pageNum in range(1, ddp.pageCount + 1):  
   ddp.currentPageID = pageNum  
   print "Saving %s.mxd" %(ddp.pageRow.getValue(c))  
   mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\jcarl\Desktop\Presentation\MXD\\" + ddp.pageRow.getValue(c) + ".mxd")  
  del mxd
```

like i said it works if i just use a, or b, but not together.  I am trying to export as attribute (attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value from column 'L_NAME' and 'PAR_NUM' seperately. Currently your code `ddp.pageRow.getValue(c)` is looking for a column called 'L_NAMEPAR_NUM'. Delete the lines `a = 'L_NAME'`, `b = 'PAR_NUM'`, and `c = a + b`.

After `ddp.currentPageID = pageNum`, try this:

```
a = ddp.pageRow.getValue('L_NAME')
b = ddp.pageRow.getValue('PAR_NUM')
c = a + b

print "Saving %s.mxd" %(c)
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\jcarl\Desktop\Presentation\MXD/" + c + ".mxd")
```