# Auto Exporting Individual PDFs from Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, export, pdf, data-driven-pages

I am trying to figure out how best to modify this script from Esri so that instead of exporting all of my data driven pages into one PDF, it exports each page to its own PDF, while also naming the exported PDF from a value in the indexed data driven pages table. Note, the syntax uses .png but I would want to alter it to export pdfs instead.

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
  mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\ParcelAtlas_Page" + str(pageNum) + ".png")
del mxd
```

For context, the DDPs step through each "node boundary" where the page is setup to contain the individual features that share that boundary. I want to export out a PDF for each boundary and name the PDF what the boundary is called. In the end, I should have exact the same amount of PDFs as there are boundaries in the data.

What I am assuming needs to happen is that I need to define a variable in the for loop that represents the node boundary attribute in the attribute table, then I need to concatenate the node boundary variable with ".pdf". Its been so long since I've used python so its frustrating I can't figure out something that I feel should be basic.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132739/export-individual-mapbook-pages-to-pdf

Comment: Yes! I just can't get it to name the file based off of the field in the attribute table. I got the script to work but it would only export each PDF with the name of the folder followed by sequential numbers (like Test Export1, Test Export2, etc.). I saw the follow up comment tried to introduce a variable based on the page number which I THINK is the indexed field but that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: See how it's done https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129707/concatenating-variable-values-in-python-script-for-export-ddp-as-mxd-via-saveaco

Comment: This seems to export each page as its own MXD. What I am trying to do is export each page within the data driven pages to its own separate PDF using the index value of the pages as the name.

Answer (score 2):

If post I referred you to is not enough, see if this will do.

Input pages table:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")  
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages  
for pageNum in range(1, ddp.pageCount + 1):  
    ddp.currentPageID = pageNum
    fName = "F:/aerials/PDFs/"+ddp.pageRow.getValue('PDF_NAME')+".pdf"
    ddp.exportToPDF(fName,"CURRENT",resolution=144)
```

Outputs:

[image]